# Area of a surface defined by two functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the area of the surface defined by 
$$x + y + z = 1$$ 
$$x^2 + 2y^2 \leq 1$$

I'm having trouble finding the parametrization of the surface

Comment: Try parameterizing the second region first, and then impose the first equation as a constraint. How many free parameters should you have?

Comment: For sure you are looking at the area of an ellipse...I helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you think, just look at $$x^2 + 2y^2 = (x)^2 + (\sqrt{2}y)^2 = 1$$
Since $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta = 1$, to parametrize the boundary above, $x = \cos v$ and $y = \frac {\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin v$, with $v \in [0, 2\pi [$ will do. To get the interior of the region, we make the "radius" vary, as $x = u \cos v$ and $y = u\frac {\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin v$, for $u \in [0,1]$. If $u = 0$, we get the origin, if $u = 1 $ we're back to the boundary. But the first condition states that $z = 1 - x - y $. Since we already have $x$ and $y$, the wanted parametrization is: $$\mathbf{x}(u,v) = \left(u \cos v, u \frac {\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin v, 1 - u\cos v - u\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin v\right) \qquad (u,v) \in [0,1] \times [0, 2\pi [$$